# Between Dates Query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2016

I had a question up earlier and it was pretty much solved expect one part of it. for some reason its not showing me between dates for my query. Just the dates that i enter in the parameter. i was wondering if anyone can see any problem with the code. Any help is much appreciated.

[Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYLd6.png)

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Vehicles
 WHERE Vehicles.vehicle_id NOT IN (
 SELECT Booking.[vehicle id]
 FROM Booking
 WHERE (
    [Enter Start Date] BETWEEN booking.start_rent_date
        AND booking.end_rent_date
    )
 OR (
    [Enter End Date] BETWEEN booking.start_rent_date
        AND booking.end_rent_date
    )
 );
```

[image]

Comment: I dont understand the question. Also, this seems like MS Access, not SQL.

Comment: have you tried with: `WHERE [Enter Start Date] >= booking.start_rent_date AND [Enter End Date] < booking.end_rent_date`?

Comment: @mcNets Yes i have i have been like 3 hours trying to get this right and for some reason it is refusing to work for me i dont understand why the code looks correct

Comment: Can you show us any values you are using?

Comment: And you should add the tag of your DBMS.

Comment: @mcNets  im trying to use the values 01/11/2016 between 20/11/2016.... so i shouldnt see any vehicle that is booked between these dates but it isnt working for me. maybe the top bit of the code is incorrect

Comment: Post sample data so we can reproduce this.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter is it possible to post my database on here.. if not i can run the query and screen shot my results

Comment: No. Just post your table structure and some sample data.  But first, tag this question with the appropriate DBMS.

Comment: Man, what dates are you using?  where are defined [enter start date] and [end start date]?

Comment: @mcNets  thats a parameter i am running where i enter the dates i am looking so for enter start date i enter when the car will be rented out and when it will be returned... is that any help i also posted the table structure

Comment: @EatPeanutButter i posted the table structures there

Comment: OK, now tag this with your database vendor, not just 'database'

Comment: something about MSAccess, dates, and `#` around them.. can't remember if parameters required the `#` though...

Comment: @xQbert what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed that [Enter End Date] is greater than [Enter Start Date].

First, try if this single query works fine:

```
SELECT Booking.*
FROM Booking
WHERE (((Booking.start_rent_date)>#2016/11/1#) 
      AND ((Booking.end_rent_date)<#2016/11/20#));
```

Second, try to join with distinct values:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vehicles
WHERE Vehicles.vehicle_id NOT IN 
            (
            SELECT distinct Booking.[vehicle id]
            FROM Booking
            WHERE (((Booking.start_rent_date)>#2016/11/1#) 
            AND ((Booking.end_rent_date)<#2016/11/20#))
            );
```

Comment: its still not working man no vehicles are returning when i run the query, is it possible to message you the database so you can see it yourself

Comment: Yes i am using MS Acess 2016

Comment: just tried the new one there and still no vehicles are being shown for it idk where i have gone wrong

Comment: Yeah i just did... maybe my code near the top is messed up or something

Comment: it would mean the world man i have been a couple of hours at this tryign to solve it and looked all over the web and i just cant understand why it aint working for me

Comment: i also have a middle table called vehicles rented connected between both of those tables i dont know if that is making the query not working

Comment: ok, try this sentence, add a new view and use 'View SQL' to add the text

Comment: yes that filters the bookings for me between those dates

Comment: i tried that second one man and i am not getting other results back... did you want me to post it on top of the other query

Comment: ill post the relationships i have so you can see them in the main post

Comment: i posted the relationships there in the main one

Comment: There is a table between Vehicles and Booking, try building a view with `Vehicles` and  `Vehicles Rented` and then change `Vehicles` table in the query above.

Comment: i tried deleting the table and it wouldnt work for me is there anyway i can send you my access file and for you to look at it... i can shoot ya a few bucks on paypal for your time

Comment: No thanks but I have my job, I'm here trying to help, but is not my business. In my opinion, if the first query works (vehicleid between dates), you can work around it and get the solution. Build a view of vehicles and vehicles rented that shows vehicle_id and booking.*, call it vbooking, verify it works fine, then replace vehicles table in the second query by vbooking.

Comment: thats cool man thanks im guessing it is to do with the way my relationships is set up ill have to try and find a way around it